# Existence of extension field containing all roots of a polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is not for homework, but I would just like a hint please.  The question asks

> If $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ has degree $n$, show that there exists an extension field $\mathbb{E}$ of $\mathbb{F}$ such that $\mathbb{E}$ contains all the roots of $f(x)$.

I believe induction is the way to go with this problem.  In the case of $n = 1$, the extension field $\mathbb{F}[x]/(f(x))$ of $\mathbb{F}$ contains the root of $f(x)$.  Suppose the claim is true for $\deg (f(x)) < n$ for some $n \geq 2$.

Suppose $\deg (f(x)) = n$.  I know there is an extension field $\mathbb{K}$ of $\mathbb{F}$ that contains at least one root, say $c_n$, of $f(x)$.  Now I can write $f(x) = (x - c_n)g(x)$, where $\deg (g(x)) < n$.  The induction hypothesis then implies there exists an extension field $\mathbb{E}$ of $\mathbb{F}$ such that $\mathbb{E}$ contains all the roots of $g(x)$.  Now, all the roots of $g(x)$ are also roots of $f(x)$.  The part that is confusing me is that I have these *two* fields $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{K}$ containing all the roots of $f(x)$.  Can I combine them somehow to get just one field containing the roots of $f(x)$?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In "the induction hypothesis" do the extension **on** $\;\Bbb K\;$ , not on $\;\Bbb F\;$! That's the whole trick here...

Comment: @DonAntonio Aha! Silly me. That fixes it. Thank you!

Comment: Do not forget that coefficients of $g(x)$ lie in that extension field $K$, not in $F$. So the induction hypothesis can only give you an extension field of $K$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Could you post that as an answer? [We](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12092557#12092557) are trying to reduce the number of questions in "unanswered" tab. I will upvote! Thanks :)

Comment: Okee=dokee, @Prism. Answer on its way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your way is the way to go, only taking into account what's in the comments:

$$f(x)\in\Bbb F[x]\;\;\text{irreducible}\implies \alpha:=x+\langle f(x)\rangle\in\Bbb K:=\Bbb F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;\text{is a root of}\;f(x)$$

so that $\;f(x)=(x-\alpha)g(x)\;$ **in** $\;\Bbb K[x]\;$ and $\;[\Bbb K:\Bbb F]=n:=\deg f(x)\;$ .

Repeat the above (inductively) for $\;g(x)\;$ **in** $\;\Bbb K[x]\;$ (or one of its irreducible factors in case it is not irreducible over $\;\Bbb K\;$) and voilá, since $\;\deg g(x)<n\;$ .